# Why does my switch debouncing circuit still result in occasional false presses?

Tags: switches, stm32, debounce

I have an issue where my switch debouncing implementation isn't working. I have a custom STM32 board with switches connected to an interrupt pin on the STM32. The pin is configured to be interrupt on rising edge. My issue however is that ocassionally the push-button switch will trigger on a depress and then also a release - resulting in two presses detected, when it should detect only on the release. My debouncing schematic:
[image]

The switches are wired to the outside of a steel enclosure, with the wire length being approximately 300mm.

I think what is happening is that on depress, there is a small amount of oscillation that is slow enough for the stm32 to detect. On the scope:
[image]

and then zoomed in here I have these oscillations that look to exceed the threshold for a trigger on the STM32. These aren't always present:

[image]

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: presumably the switch is from the port to 0V? you don't actually tell us.

Comment: The pin is pulled high and then the button press pulls the pin low. I thought that it was obvious from the schematic and the scope capture, but I can edit the question.

Comment: also note (if my assumption i correct) that this circuit can apply small negative spikes directly to the IO port, which is not good - due to C being charged when the switch is open, and not being able to discharge instantaneously when you close it. The pulse is small ( a few us) but you might damage your IO pins over time as you exceed the recommended voltage range.

Comment: you find it obvious and so do I but good engineers do not assume things. If you want info about debouncing a switch it makes sense to actually show the switch you want to debounce.

Comment: You need to show the whole wiring route of the switch from the IO port, through the switch and back to 0 volts/GND. You could also estimate the loop inductance too.

Comment: One problem of using interrupts is the fact that noise, ringing, spikes, and switch just being scratchy generates multiple edges. Also slowing down the signal may just spend too much time on the transition zone which will result to multiple interrupts. Your RC filter is also unusual, a short glitch does not discharge the cap via resistor and it jump right back to high. So please justify the use of a) interrupts and b) the weird circuit.

Comment: Use an RS-FF for real hardware debouncing. Spdt with center point at inputs

Comment: You have 2 time constants on the go.  R70 C49 on button press (short) and (R67 + R70) C49 (long) on button release, which is shown on your first scope image.  Personally, I would of switched the caps and the 100Ω resistors.

Comment: Everything you'll ever want to know about hardware debouncing:  http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your describe filtering the bounce pulses from the switch signal and using it to generate an STM32 MCU interrupt. But the filter design only removes 10's us of bounce from switches which typically bounce for many milliseconds, with many switch datasheets in the range 3..10 ms.

It is simpler for the MCU to debounce the switch in software. This requires a regular timer interrupt, say every 5..10 ms, to be running to sample the switch levels at a fixed interval. The switch inputs will no longer be configured as interrupt inputs but just as GPIO inputs. Only the timer will generate interrupts for the switches.

This saves circuit components while putting extra workload on the MCU software. However, the workload is very low on the typical 10's/100's MHz MCU processing of these days.

The interrupt service routine (ISR) switch procedure is as follows, where `gpioSw` is the switch input and all others are RAM variables:

```
\\ Read switch level into a three-stage history buffer.
swOld2 := swOld1
swOld1 := swNew
swNew := gpioSw

\\ Keep previous debounced switch level for change detection later.
dbSwitchOld  :=  dbSwitch

\\ Accept the switch level as debounced when steady for three samples in a row.
if (swNew = swOld1 and swOld1 = swOld2) then
  dbSwitch  :=  swNew
end if

if (dbSwitch = 0 and dbSwitchOld = 1) then
  \\ Key pressed.
end if;

if (dbSwitch = 1 and dbSwitchOld = 0) then
  \\ Key released.
end if;
```

The algorithm can use RAM load/store instructions and logical operations. So to handle multiple switches, the software can use the same algorithm to put into bits of a single `gpioSw` dword/etc. and use dword/etc. variables to debounce all switches simultaneously. Only the software to react to each switch need be unique.

Answer (score 5):

Your circuit is a bit naive. It will work most of the time, but your time constant is only 100 x 0.1 uS which is 10 us. Mechanical switches typically bounce bounce for 3-10 milliseconds, perhaps more - it may (or not) be specified on the datasheet. Also you should ideally connect a diode from the port to ground (reverse-biased, of course) to get rid of negative spikes as you close the switch.

In general, you'd be better doing this in software, as you will find yourself using larger and larger CR combinations to get the longer time constant you need, and even then it may be troublesome (because you also rely on the exact threshold voltage at the port). Longer debounce times are trivial in software and typically work very well once well tuned.

With 30cm of wire to the external enclosure, I would also want to add at least some series resistance and likely other components to protect your IO port against failures due to ESD (which can be a big issue when someone walks over a dry carpet and presses the switch before touching the chassis of the equipment).

Comment: Generally a good answer but a couple of points. "*Some switches can bounce for several milliseconds*" That should read that typical mechanical contact switch bounce times are in the order of 3..10 ms and to refer to their datasheet. "*failures due to EMC*" You meant ESD, which you go on to describe.

Comment: I agree with the software comment, but one issue is that if the button is pressed and held and a false detect occurs on the press/hold due to oscillations on the press, there will still be another interrupt generated on button release.

Comment: @ChrisD91 not really. Just get it to interrupt when it is high, then use your software debounce, check to see if the switch is still in the high state (valid press), and if it isn't, ignore it until interrupted again

Comment: @ChrisD91, quite, you should't have bounce pulses generating interrupts. But this would most often use a timer interrupt to regularly sample the switch level, only accepting it as high or low when sampled several times in the same state e.g. same for 3 passes of a 5 ms interrupt.

Comment: @TonyM, you're absolutely right, I can't believe I didn't think of just sampling more than once before. Now the interrupt starts a timer (rather than making a decision) and then I actually read the pin to check if it's low and do this a few times over 100ms. If it continues to be low over that time then it's a press. A glitch just restarts timer.

Comment: @ChrisD91, a bit different to that, so have posted it as an answer.

Comment: @TonyM yes good observations, edited, thank you.